# Imagemagick : unknown field with tag 37724

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff

to convert TIF file on JPG file, i'm using ImageMagick.

But on some files, I have the following error :

unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/704.

I read some topic about this problem on ImageMagick forum, but I did'nt know why these files could be ave this error.

Any idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an ImageMagick bug:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16390